# If $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ complex matrices , then $AB-BA=I$ is impossible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> If $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ complex matrices , then $AB-BA=I$ is
>   impossible

I understand this by any example. But how can one explain it generally?

Comment: what do you mean by *explain*? Do you want some maybe some graphical intuition?

Comment: It has an interesting generalization for (possibly infinite dimensional) linear operators.

Comment: @Santiago I would be interested by a reference to this generalization.

Comment: @JeanMarie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem

Comment: I would like to draw the attention to the quantum physical applications of such relationships in particular to $QP-PQ=i\hslash$ ($\hslash$ is the normalized Plank's constant) which appeared for the first time in an article of Heisenberg in 1927(http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-uncertainty/).

Comment: @Santiago Thanks very much.

Answer (score 14):

Observe that $\mathrm{tr}(AB-BA)=0$, while $\mathrm{tr}(I)=n$.

Answer (score 5):

Another way could be to try the **multiplicative identity**

$$\det({\bf AB}) = \det({\bf A})\det({\bf B})$$

And consider the relation between determinant and eigenvalues

$$\det({\bf X})=\prod_{i=0}^{n} \lambda_i({\bf X})$$

together with the perturbation of eigenvalues by addition of identity:

$$\lambda_k({\bf X+I}) = 1+\lambda_k({\bf X})$$